# cs50 Pset 6 DNA - Issue creating list

Tags: python-3.x, cs50, dna-sequence

I have a code which iterates through the text, and tells me which is the maximum amount of times each dna STR is found. The only step missing to be able to match these values with the CSV file, is to store them into a list, BUT I AM NOT ABLE TO DO SO. When I run the code, the maximum values are printed independently for each STR sequence.
I have tried to "append" the values into a list, but I was not successful, thus, I cannot match it with the dna sequences of the CSV (large nor small).
Any help or advcise is greatly appreciated!
Here is my code, and the results I get with using "text 1" and "small csv":
`

```
import cs50
import sys
import csv
import os

if len(sys.argv) != 3:
    print("Usage: python dna.py data.csv sequence.txt")
csv_db = sys.argv[1]
file_seq = sys.argv[2]


with open(csv_db, newline='') as csvfile: #with open(csv_db) as csv_file
    csv_reader = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=',')
    header = next(csv_reader)
    i = 1
    while i < len(header):
        STR = header[i]
        len_STR = len(STR)
        with open(file_seq, 'r') as my_file:
            file_reader = my_file.read()
            counter = 0
            a = 0
            b = len_STR
            list = []
            for text in file_reader:
                if file_reader[a:b] != STR:
                    a += 1
                    b += 1
                else:
                    counter += 1
                    a += len_STR
                    b += len_STR
        list.append(counter)
        print(list)
        i += 1
```

`

Answer (score 1):

The problem is in place of variable "list" declaration. Every time you iterates through STRs in variable "header" you declares:

```
list = []
```

Thus, you create absolutely new variable, which stores only the length of current STR. To make a list with all STRs appended you need to declare variable "list" before the while loop and operator "print" after the while loop:

```
list = []
while i < len(header):
    <your loop code>
print(list)
```

This should solve your problem.

P.S. Avoid to use "list" as a variable declaration. The "list" is a python built-in function and it is automatically declared. So, when you redeclare it, you will not be able to use list() function in your code.